# Is there a faster way to search something in an array than in_array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, performance, search

I need to check some input string against a huge (and growing) list of strings coming from a CSV file (1000000+). I currently load every string in an array and check against it via in_array(). Code looks like this:

```
$filter = array();
$filter = ReadFromCSV();

$input = array("foo","bar" /* more elements... */);
foreach($input as $i){
  if(in_array($i,$filter)){
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

It already takes some time and I was wondering is there is a faster way to do this?

Comment: Maybe you should think about using a DB instead of reading the values from CSV into memory each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`in_array()` checks every element in the array until it finds a match. The average complexity is O(n).

Since you are comparing strings, you might store your input as array *keys* instead of *values* and look them up via `array_key_exists();` which requires a constant time O(1).

Some code:

```
$filter = array();
$filter = ReadFromCSV();
$filter = array_flip($filter); // switch key <=> value

$input = array("foo","bar" /* more elements... */);
foreach($input as $i){
  if(array_key_exists($i,$filter)){ // array_key_exists();
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow.. that really makes a difference. Why can't in_array be that fast?

Comment: It only works that `easy` because you are comparing strings. Array key types are restricted to `integer` and `string` whereas array values can be anything.

Answer (score 0):

That's what indexes were invented for.

It's not a matter of in_array() speed, as the data grows, you should probably consider using indexes by loading data into a real DBMS.